# Using ArrayList of ArrayList to print random Toast message in Android

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, random

I'm trying to work through some Android Java stuff and I'm having some trouble working out a Toast message. My scope is being able to post a random toast message from an array of strings that was called from another ArrayList. I figured out how to print them out separately though I feel I might be missing a lot when it comes to the toast syntax since.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView myListView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        final ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<>(asList("Giovani", "Enu", "Xochle", "Rquel", "Falsto", "Bam", "Duncan", "Goose", "Edgar", "Frank"));

        ArrayList<String> gio = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other brother ", " Met in high school ", " Played on the same sports team ", " Has two kids "));
        ArrayList<String> karina = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His youngest sister ", " Kinda short ", " Sweet but kinda dumb "));
        ArrayList<String> midget = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His Second youngest sister ", " Kinda short ", " Kinda a crazy cat lady ", " Cannot handle her liquor "));
        ArrayList<String> ma = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other mother ", " Works way too hard ", " Sweetest lady in the world "));
        ArrayList<String> pa = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other father ", " Not feeling well ", " Good heart hopefully he can live in peace "));
        ArrayList<String> me = new ArrayList<>(asList(" The coolest ", " Kinda short ", " Sweet but kinda dumb "));
        ArrayList<String> dunks = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Brother from another mother ", " Warrior born ", " Allergic to most things that could hinder combat "));
        ArrayList<String> gus = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other brother ", " Loves cars ", " Talks alot of shit ", " Loves white girls ", " Memorised the metal gear series by heart"));
        ArrayList<String> edd = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Oldest of the other brother ", " Mostly quiet outside of social situations ", " Cares about saving his money ", " Laughs alot"));
        ArrayList<String> frank = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Other brother ", " Impulsively stupid but loyal ", " Really into recreational passions "));

        //ArrayList[] fList = new ArrayList[]{{myFamily.get(0),Bio.get()}, };

        final Random chance = new Random();

        final ArrayList<ArrayList> bio = new ArrayList (Arrays.asList(gio, karina, midget, ma, pa, me, dunks, gus, edd, frank));
        //final int selectChance = chance.nextInt(bio.length);
        /*
        for (String selection : myFamily)
            bio
            return ;

        }
        */

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayManager = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFamily);

        myListView.setAdapter(arrayManager);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sup " + bio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So You have a list view which contains Names like `Giovani` or `Enu` and the when You click on that item You want to Toast random message from the list which contains sentences for that name so e.g. for `Giovani` You want to print the random string from `gio`? Am I correct?

Comment: @iknow yes thats what I'm aiming for yes

Comment: So look at my answer, I think it does what You want. If not tell me, otherwise You can upvote and accept :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood You correctly You can Add this to Your `onItemClick`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
{
    int randomIndex = chance.nextInt(bio.get(i).size()); // generate random number between 0 and and array size
    String randomString = bio.get(i).get(randomIndex); // take value from random index
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Sup " + randomString,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
}
```

---

Full code of main activity (I made only small changes so above solution should work for You):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView myListView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        final ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<>(asList("Giovani",
                                                                  "Enu",
                                                                  "Xochle",
                                                                  "Rquel",
                                                                  "Falsto",
                                                                  "Bam",
                                                                  "Duncan",
                                                                  "Goose",
                                                                  "Edgar",
                                                                  "Frank"
        ));

        ArrayList<String> gio = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other brother ",
                                                       " Met in high school ",
                                                       " Played on the same sports team ",
                                                       " Has two kids "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> karina = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His youngest sister ",
                                                          " Kinda short ",
                                                          " Sweet but kinda dumb "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> midget = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His Second youngest sister ",
                                                          " Kinda short ",
                                                          " Kinda a crazy cat lady ",
                                                          " Cannot handle her liquor "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> ma = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other mother ",
                                                      " Works way too hard ",
                                                      " Sweetest lady in the world "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> pa = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other father ",
                                                      " Not feeling well ",
                                                      " Good heart hopefully he can live in peace "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> me = new ArrayList<>(asList(" The coolest ",
                                                      " Kinda short ",
                                                      " Sweet but kinda dumb "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> dunks = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Brother from another mother ",
                                                         " Warrior born ",
                                                         " Allergic to most things that could hinder combat "
        ));
        ArrayList<String> gus = new ArrayList<>(asList(" His other brother ",
                                                       " Loves cars ",
                                                       " Talks alot of shit ",
                                                       " Loves white girls ",
                                                       " Memorised the metal gear series by heart"
        ));
        ArrayList<String> edd = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Oldest of the other brother ",
                                                       " Mostly quiet outside of social situations ",
                                                       " Cares about saving his money ",
                                                       " Laughs alot"
        ));
        ArrayList<String> frank = new ArrayList<>(asList(" Other brother ",
                                                         " Impulsively stupid but loyal ",
                                                         " Really into recreational passions "
        ));

        final Random chance = new Random();

        final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bio = new ArrayList<>(asList(gio,
                                                                        karina,
                                                                        midget,
                                                                        ma,
                                                                        pa,
                                                                        me,
                                                                        dunks,
                                                                        gus,
                                                                        edd,
                                                                        frank
        ));

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayManager = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                                                               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                               myFamily
        );

        myListView.setAdapter(arrayManager);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                int randomIndex = chance.nextInt(bio.get(i).size());
                String randomString = bio.get(i).get(randomIndex);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Sup " + randomString,
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much You cant believe how much of a headache this has given me!!!

Comment: @BernardMesh You are welcome :D so I conclude that my answer was useful, to accept it click "check sign" below votes. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)